# Microservice authentication implementation using GKE gateway

Tags: authentication, microservices, google-kubernetes-engine, api-gateway

I am quite new to GKE gateway and I'm trying to implement the below architecture for user authentication in microservices using a GKE gateway:

[The target architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5dXj.png)

The Authorization server is a custom service that authenticates the users and replaces the access token with a jwt token. I have been struggling with finding a way to have GKE gateway request the third-party Authorization server and replace the access token with the new jwt token. The Authorization server supports multiple authentication methods as well as a few custom ones. On the other hand, the access token has limited information inside while the replaced jwt token includes more specific information about the authenticated user which is retrieved by the Authorization server and placed in the jwt token.

I have looked into [httpfilter](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/reference/spec/#gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1.HTTPHeaderFilter) and [httproute](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/reference/spec/#gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1alpha2.HTTPRoute) for possible solutions but I haven't found anything that I can use. Does anyone know how I can implement this scenario?

Thank you!